# Как программно получить данные о памяти, как в диспетчере задач Windows?

Tags: windows, любой-язык, memory-management

С помощью API-функции, которую для этого дела везде советуют, получил данные, выделенные красным и синим.
[image: https://i.imgur.com/qRWjqV7.png]

Как запросить значение, выделенное зелёным?
Находил пример через .NET и параметр RawValue, но мне бы без .NET хотелось... Возможно это через WinAPI получить? (В русском Win вроде этот столбик называется "Частный рабочий набор")

Answer (score 0):

То, размер чего вам нужен, называется "private working set". А получить его можно из класса [Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//aa394323(v=vs.85)), поле `PrivateBytes`. Там по ссылке, внизу есть примеры для C++ и для каких-то скриптовых языков.

Comment: ага, спасибо, попробую на досуге... Но мне всегда казалось WMI не самым лучшим решением... я бы это использовал, если бы вся программа имела целью опрашивать всевозможные параметры компьютера, но, когда нужна одна циферка, думаю это перебор... Да и эти WQL запросы, думаю далеко не быстро работают... Хотя, может я заблуждаюсь, надо попробовать. Но если есть другие варианты, буду раз услышать.

Comment: @Isaev, смотря какая циферка. Многие можно и без WMI получить, но вам же понадобилось нечто особенное.